# Is Quorra human now?

Tags: tron-legacy, tron

As a corollary to my other [question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/28875/how-does-sam-bleed) I was wondering about this:

Once Quorra enters the real world does she become human or is she something else? i.e. Is she a living, breathing, human being with blood, sweat, and tears, is she some kind of human appearing 'alien', or is she a synthetic creation like a robot?

Comment: I really don't like the title of this question. I'm not sure it is much a spoiler to say either the character's name or maybe "Are entities leaving the Grid human now?" As it stands the title isn't very useful to anyone.

Comment: I've changed it, didn't want to have spoilers for the ending of the movie but it does kind of cramp the question

Comment: I find the lack of hot pictures of Olivia Wilde in leather to be quite disconcerting.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Flynn spoke about Quorra as a solution to all of the real world's problems.

> Kevin Flynn: Yeah. The last ISO.
>    Sam Flynn: All this time, you were just protecting her.
>    Kevin Flynn: She's the miracle, man. Everything I ever worked for. "A digital frontier to reshape the human condition."
>    Sam Flynn: I always thought that was a plug line.
>    Kevin Flynn: In our world, she can change everything.

This leads me to the conclusion that she didn't rematerialize as a human. Or maybe she is the perfect human, with no flaws (ie such as maybe no genetic flaws, or perfect disease immunity or something). I don't think she is an android, if a program came through it would just try to complete its programming. Perhaps she is a new lifeform that takes on the shape of a human.

This is the same answer I gave to a similar [question](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/4065/211) on Movies.SE.

Comment: Although, if anyone can enter the grid and they get an identity disk then shouldn't it be possible to "fix" a regular human while they are there?

Comment: *"This leads me to the conclusion that she didn't rematerialize as a human."* I disagree. The digitizing laser can obviously turn a human into a digital entity, and vice versa (how else would Flynn get back to the real world?) Think of the laser as being a translator, of sorts.

Comment: Well _obviously_ Sam went through with flesh and blood intact (he bleeds when cut by Rinzler). I see no reason why Quorra wouldn't come through with a programs/ISOs "glass" body. Programs feel fear/pleasure/pain with those bodies. The digitizer _obviously_ translates that into real world _stuff_. (_obviously_ here is used because this is one movie you don't want to start poking holes in, or it all falls apart very quickly).

Answer (score 3):

My (very) speculative answer is that Quorra is indeed a flesh and blood human. The laser in the original *Tron* was capable of "digitizing" matter into information stored in memory while suspending atoms or molecules in the laser, and then reconstituting the object at a later time (see [here](http://tron.wikia.com/wiki/Digitization) for a brief description).

Since Flynn and Sam were both successfully digitized and reconstituted using this technology, it stands to reason that Flynn could "build" a human being from scratch given proper ingredients (e.g., ~ 140 lbs of atoms of the right type and proportions: C, H, O, N, etc.) + assembly instructions. The assembly part would be difficult to code to say the least, but perhaps Flynn could use a shortcut by borrowing assembly code from other humans that had been scanned in.

[image]
<sub><sup>[**The Art of Tron: Legacy**](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Art-Tron-Legacy-Justin-Springer/dp/1423131495)</sup></sub>

Comment: According to the Art of Tron : Legacy book, the tubes under the digitising laser are used to contain the CHON elements. In the absence of those elements, how could the laser turn her into a flesh and blood human?

Comment: @Richard - Good question. One possibility is that the digitising laser was still storing Flynn's atoms from his final trip into the Grid. After Sam returned to our world, Quorra could have "borrowed" Flynn's atoms when she was reintegrated as a human being (which perhaps CLU was planning on doing had his plan succeeded). It's also possible Flynn maintained backup tanks of elements in storage in his secret office under the arcade.

Comment: Good call. I forgot there was already a set of elements in the tanks.

Answer (score 2):

In 'Legacy', it is clearly depicted that Humans [Users] when injured in the digital world, bleed what resembles blood -- instead of simply derezzing as the native programs do.  This suggests the internal organs of Users are at least structurally reminiscent of their anatomy from the real world.

Quora is depicted, as having a digital DNA in her resuscitation/repair scene, which presumably is what marks her (and the ISO's) as being inherently different from the other programs.

This leads me to hypothesise that she is genetically prepared to survive digital manifestation through portal to the physical world.  Which is why Flynn (the Elder) is so incredibly excited about the discovery of the ISO's

Does that mean she would bleed little fluorescent blue cubes in the real world?

I can't say, but I would hypothesise her internal structure in the real world would be akin to her digital self -- and vastly different from our own.

"Biomechanical Jazz" as Kevin Flynn puts it.

---

This brings up the question whether a Regular Program could be materialized in the real world.

CLU clearly thinks so -- because his whole world-domination plan hinges on the ability to bring an army of programs through the portal.

However it is never demonstrated in either of the films whether it is possible for a regular program to be materialized.

Answer (score -4):

A human goes trough the "portal"  to the grid and they, not being data, is "translated" into code. The same goes the other way around.

Comment: Do you have any references to back up this idea? Does this definitively occur in any of the books, shows, etc? In the movies, Quorra is the only being to originate as digital and enter the "real world".

Comment: As I said, the jury is still out. Maybe Jeff Bridges knows the answer.